# jQuery .next selector ignores the generated div and targets the next div - how can I target the sibling div

Tags: jquery

I am trying to target a div that is generated by a jQuery plugin. I have been trying to do this using **.next** but with no luck.

***Update**: Please note this generated div is triggered by a click*

***Update**:Here is a fiddle of the code http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/PAbAH/1/

The problem is, the next selector ignores the generated div and targets the next div. I understand that this is not working because the generated div is technically not a sibling.

Does anyone have an idea how I can target this elusive generated div. I can't use css because I only want to hide it when it is generated from certain links.

**Code example**

```
//Script
$("div.region_marker").next("div.bubble").hide();

//HTML
<div class="region_marker">Region Marker text</div> //this is how I am targeting the generated div
<div class="bubble">Bubble text</div> //div generated by jQuery, not hard coded, this is ignored by .next
<div class="map_marker">Map Marker text</div> //random div, this is the one that .next targets
<div class="map_marker">Map Marker text</div> //random div
```

I am open to any suggestions you have, thanks guys

Comment: Post your code, please. Whether or not jQuery added the element should make no difference.

Comment: There has to be [more to it than meets the eye](http://jsfiddle.net/eJcx9/)... (I'm guessing the insert script is called _after_ DOM load, but you're script is being called _before_ (so it's _technically_ not added it when jQuery goes to find it)

Comment: Code looks fine to me. Could it be a timimg issue? i.e. is the bubble div already generated when you execute your code?

Comment: Hi guys, thanks, I think you might be mad at me though because I forgot to mention that the div.bubble is generated by a click. I have a link that targets the div.region_marker co-ordinates, this also triggers the div.bubble popup. So sorry guys I didn't mention it before.

Comment: I have posted a jsfiddle here, http://jsfiddle.net/clintongreen/PAbAH/1/ this is all using mobily map btw. Cheers

Comment: Thanks everyone, I got it working using:  $("div.region_marker").click(function() {
 $(this).next(".bubble").hide();
});
All your comments about timing and and in what order it was loaded helped me. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks I got it working using:

$("div.region_marker").click(function() { $(this).next(".bubble").hide(); });

It works now using the click function to trigger this at the same time, the traditional methods were not working because I ran those functions before the div.bubble was loaded.

Answer (score 1):

If it's a child, use `.find()`.  If it's a sibling and the very next sibling, use `.next()`.  If it's a next sibling, but not the very next sibling, then use `.nextAll()`.

In your code, this will get the "Bubble text" div generated by jQuery:

```
$("div.region_marker").next();
```

This will get the first Map Marker text div:

```
$("div.region_marker").nextAll(".map_marker").first();
```

If you really want to hide the first .bubble sibling, then you can use this:

```
$("div.region_marker").nextAll(".bubble").first().hide();
```

The only reason that last one would work and your code would not is if the order of the tags isn't quite what you think it is.

P.S. Using selectors like `div.bubble` and `div.region_marker` is not necessary unless you're trying to eliminate other types of tags that might have that class.  In your situation, you can just use `.region_marker` and `.bubble` and save the selector engine a little work.

Comment: Thanks jfriend, I tried out .nextAll but it didn't work out. I updated my question because I forgot to mention that the generated div is triggered from a click. Sorry I forgot to mention this before, I'm sure this is why none of the traditional ways are working. Cheers

Comment: It doesn't matter why the div was generated.  All that matters is what is it's position in the DOM.  If these aren't working, it's because your DOM hierarchy is not how you think it is.  You will need to either shows us the real DOM hierarchy or the code that inserts the generated DIV so we can see what the structure really looks like.  If you structure was as you said it was, all these would work - so something in your HTML structure is not as you think it is.

Comment: Thanks I got it working using: $("div.region_marker").click(function() { $(this).next(".bubble").hide(); });

Comment: When I finally succeed in getting a .bubble class to appear, it is NOT the next sibling after the `.region_marker`.  There are some points in between.  I think you should use the last suggestion in my answer of `$("div.region_marker").nextAll(".bubble").first().hide();` so it will just use the next sibling that matches, even if there are intervening objects.

Comment: Hi jfriend, sorry i just tried that out on the site and it didn't work, it seems it needed to use the click event to hide it. Thanks for all your help. Cheers